# Datetime in pandas dataframe will not subtract from each other

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, subtraction

I am trying to find the difference in times between two columns in a pandas dataframe both in datetime format.

Below is some of the data in my dataframe and the code I have been using. I have triple checked that these two columns dtypes are datetime64.

My data:

```
date_updated                  date_scored 
2016-03-30 08:00:00.000       2016-03-30 08:00:57.416  
2016-04-07 23:50:00.000       2016-04-07 23:50:12.036
```

My code:

```
data['date_updated'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_updated'], 
format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data['date_scored'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_scored'], 
format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data['Diff'] =  data['date_updated'] - data['date_scored']
```

The error message I receive:

```
TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

My work around solution:

```
for i in raw_data[:10]:
scored = i.date_scored
scored_date =  pd.to_datetime(scored, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if type(scored_date) == "NoneType":
    pass
elif scored_date.year >= 2016:
    extracted = i.date_extracted
    extracted =  pd.to_datetime(extracted, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    bank = i.bank.name
    diff = scored - extracted
    datum = [str(bank), str(extracted), str(scored), str(diff)]
    data.append(datum)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? Also, are you sure you're substracting individual dates? Your code suggests you're substracting DateTimeIndex  objects, in which case

`data['date_updated'].difference(data['date_scored'])`

would serve better

Comment: Worked fine for me... also, I don't think you need the `format` parameter.  pandas will figure out that format.

Comment: I dropped the format parameter and the strings converted to datetime format nicely, however I still get TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood when running the line last line of code containing the actual subtraction...

Comment: When using the code: data['date_updated'].difference(data['date_scored'])     I get the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'difference'

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Did you ever make any progress on figuring this out?

Comment: I updated my question to show you what I ended up going with @DonQuixote However, this solution may not be applicable to you as I was dealing with data that I was querying from a mongo db, rather than a pandas df.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  For me I had to uninstall numpy and then install it again using a .whl file.  It may help someone else out if they see this in the future. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I encountered the same error using the above syntax (worked on another machine though):

```
data['Diff'] =  data['date_updated'] - data['date_scored']
```

It worked on my new machine with:

```
data['Diff'] =  data['date_updated'].subtract(data['date_scored'])
```

Comment: cool, I solved this problem a while ago - but i like this fix!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update pandas.
I've just ran into the same issue with an old code that used to run without issues. 
After updating pandas (0.18.1-np111py35_0) to a newer version (0.20.2-np113py35_0) the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm. You can even simplify your code since `to_datetime` is smart enough to guess the format for you.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
# Paste the text by using of triple-quotes to span String literals on multiple lines
zz = """date_updated,date_scored
2016-03-30 08:00:00.000,       2016-03-30 08:00:57.416  
2016-04-07 23:50:00.000,       2016-04-07 23:50:12.036"""

data = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=False, delimiter=',')

data['date_updated'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_updated'])
data['date_scored'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_scored'])
data['Diff'] =  data['date_updated'] - data['date_scored']

print(data)
#          date_updated             date_scored                     Diff
# 0 2016-03-30 08:00:00 2016-03-30 08:00:57.416 -1 days +23:59:02.584000
# 1 2016-04-07 23:50:00 2016-04-07 23:50:12.036 -1 days +23:59:47.964000
```

Comment: The data was read into a pandas df from a csv file...how do I add the io features to an existing df? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, the `import io` is just here to read the example data through the `io.StringIO(zz)` it has nothing to do to read a CSV file. So do not take it into account. What I would suggest is to try the example below as is. If it works, it means that the problem is in your data.

Comment: I got the same error with this as I do with my data...TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood

Comment: These are my three 'imports':                                                                     
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

Comment: You do not need to import `datetime`. However this does not explain the error. I think the problem may come from your python installation since the example I have provided shall work with pandas. Try to start from a fresh installation with an Anaconda distrib for example. Sorry but I don't know how to help you.

Comment: That's okay, that for you help in narrowing down the problem!